# update List View onResume (can't get view)

Tags: android, listview, onresume

I need to update my List View in onResume function, them problem is that my view is null there:

```
mList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list); //v is null
```

what should I do? how can I get my list view to update it?

Here is part of onCreate function:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.large_screen_layout);
    mList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
}
```

Here is the on resume function:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
super.onResume();

mMyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
// Here you can refresh your listview or other UI
String textmessage = intent.getStringExtra("Message");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textmessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
item = new RowItem(R.drawable.alert_icon, "text1", "text2");
rowItems.add(item);
adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.id.list,rowItems);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//now either, i need to use view (v) or mList(List View):
mList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list); //v and mList are NULL here
mList.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
};
try {
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver,new     IntentFilter("your_action"));   
} catch (Exception e)
{
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

any idea how can I update it?

Thank you!

Eran.

Comment: Where does your 'v' (the parent of your listview) comes from in your 'onReceive' function ?

Comment: Thank you all! Ill check it this evening when Ill be next to my code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
super.onResume();

mMyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
// Here you can refresh your listview or other UI
String textmessage = intent.getStringExtra("Message");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textmessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
item = new RowItem(R.drawable.alert_icon, "text1", "text2");
rowItems.add(item);
adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.id.list,rowItems);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//now either, i need to use view (v) or mList(List View):

// need to find V
View v = findViewById(R.id.large_screen_layout);

mList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list); //v and mList are NULL here
mList.setAdapter(adapter); 

}
};
try {
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver,new     IntentFilter("your_action"));   
} catch (Exception e)
{
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Also be sure to deregister your broadcast receiver in onPause or it may receive notifications in unexpected ways..

Comment: It was that simple huh?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your **OnCreate** function if you use **Activity** or **FragmentActivity**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.large_screen_layout);    
    mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
}
```

Or if u want to use **Fragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.large_screen_layout, null);
    mList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
View v = findViewById(R.id.large_screen_layout);
mList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
R.id.list,rowItems);
mList.setAdapter(adapter);} 

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMyBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String textmessage = intent.getStringExtra("Message");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), textmessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            item = new RowItem(R.drawable.alert_icon, "text1", "text2");
            rowItems.add(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    try {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("your_action"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```